# Fill column based on subsets of array

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1],
        'B': [5, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5],
        'C': list('abcdef')
    }
)
```

and an array like that

```
a = np.array([
    [1, 5],
    [3, 4]
])
```

I would now like to add an additional column `D` to `df` which contains the word `"found"` based on whether the values of `A` and `B` are contained as a subset in `a`.

A straightforward implementation would be

```
for li in a.tolist():
    m = (df['A'] == li[0]) & (df['B'] == li[1])
    df.loc[m, 'D'] = "found"
```

which gives the desired outcome

```
   A  B  C      D
0  1  5  a  found
1  2  2  b    NaN
2  3  4  c  found
3  2  1  d    NaN
4  3  4  e  found
5  1  5  f  found
```

Is there a solution which wold avoid the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is , we can use merge with `indicator`

```
out = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['A','B']),how='left',indicator="D")
out['D'] = np.where(out['D'].eq("both"),"Found","Not Found")
```

---

```
print(out)

   A  B  C          D
0  1  5  a      Found
1  2  2  b  Not Found
2  3  4  c      Found
3  2  1  d  Not Found
4  3  4  e      Found
5  1  5  f      Found
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing by using `numpy` broadcasting:

```
m = (df[['A', 'B']].values[:, None] == a).all(-1).any(-1)
df['D'] = np.where(m, 'Found', 'Not found')
```

---

```
   A  B  C          D
0  1  5  a      Found
1  2  2  b  Not found
2  3  4  c      Found
3  2  1  d  Not found
4  3  4  e      Found
5  1  5  f      Found
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1],
        'B': [5, 2, 4, 1, 4, 5],
        'C': list('abcdef')
    }
)

a = np.array([
    [1, 5],
    [3, 4]
])

df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A', 'B']), 'left', indicator="D")
D = df.pop("D")
df['D'] = 'found'
df['D'] = df['D'].where(D.eq('both'), other=np.nan)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C      D
0  1  5  a  found
1  2  2  b    NaN
2  3  4  c  found
3  2  1  d    NaN
4  3  4  e  found
5  1  5  f  found
```